# Customized Role - Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

i'm quite new to Firebase and currently having some trouble trying to implement a custom role for my project. Is there a way to set a role with only Database permissions (add and delete) and another one responsible only for Authentication? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This level of granular access control is being rolled out in the Firebase console right now. If your project has it, you'll find it by:

1. Click the <kbd>⚙︎</kbd> at the top left.
2. Click <kbd>Users and permissions</kbd>.
     [image]
3. Click the row of the user who's permission you want to change.
4. Click the <kbd>Roles</kbd> dropdown.
5. Click <kbd>Assign Firebase roles</kbd>
6. Select the roles you want to give to the user.
     [image]

You'll note that the database role is still less granular than what you want, you can simply allow the user to edit the database or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise access from project settings in firebase console.
Search for settings icon at upper left corner and then go to project settings. There will be some option of users from where you can customise access.